# Comparing time from base to loop

Tags: c#, sql

I have a small loop problem and I'm not sure how to rescue this, namely, an application that calculates worker time for the same day.
Now I have sql database of multiple arrivals (ZPZ_Von) and departures (ZPZ_Bis).
Now I need to compare the break time (the longest time) with his pause.

I could compare that to the time when I did not have a problem when the workers made a small break.

How can I get the time that lasts more than 20 minutes, is that it would be a pause and compare the same time with the time it was allocated to the shift.

This is my loop in which I could solve the problem until several arrivals (ZPZ_Von) and departures (ZPZ_Bis) appeared.

```
private void ResolveLunchPause(Work_schedule selectedShift, List<presence_time> arrivals)
{
    if (arrivals.Count > 1 && selectedShift != null)
    {
        if ((arrivals[1].ZPZ_Von - arrivals[0].ZPZ_Bis).TotalHours < selectedShift.lunch_break)
        {
            arrivals[1].ZPZ_Von = arrivals[0].ZPZ_Bis.AddHours(selectedShift.lunch_break);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example from a database with arrivals and departures

[image]

I need to check to see whether the break time is longer than 20 minutes, and if it is compared with the shift.

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Is this exemple for on employ only ? what is the expected result on this data sample?

Comment: how do you handle people starting at 11pm ending at 2am? As you store the date outside of the time ... will this be 2 line ?

Comment: @DragandDrop this is just one employee for one day, the result is currently 8:03 for the whole day, is it counting the first count, and I need to calculate the time between 12: 36-13: 34 in this case, and finally I should be the result around 09.10

Comment: From the top of my head a really ugly way: https://pastebin.com/nunJ4Gma for the biggest break.

Comment: for sum of working hour it's simply `var sumOfWorkz = new TimeSpan(input.Select(x => x.Bis.TimeOfDay - x.Von.TimeOfDay).Sum(r => r.Ticks));`

Comment: But please take a time and format this question to Something readable. 1rst Start with a list of object as data sample and provide the creation of it like I did in the sample I gave you. then explain with word all the step line by line. Should be at most 10 lines explanations. And use English name as variable ^^. Question guideline = [ask], [mcve].

Comment: @DragandDrop thank you very much for your help, your suggestions are of great importance to me.